# output from google map API returning same result

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
const request = require('request');


var geocodeAddress = (address) => {
  var encodedAddress = encodeURIComponent(address);

  request({
    url: `http://www.mapquestapi.com/geocoding/v1/address?key=APIKey&location=${encodedAddress}`,
    json: true
  }, (error, response, body) => {
    if (error) {
      console.log('Unable to connect to Google servers');
    } else if (body.results[0].locations[0].postalCode.length < 5) {
      console.log('Not a valid length of zip code.')
    } else if (body.results[0].locations[0].postalCode < 501) {
      console.log('That zip code does not exist')
    } else {
      console.log('Lat: ' + body.results[0].locations[0].latLng[0])
      console.log('Lng: ' + body.results[0].locations[0].latLng[1])
    }

  });


};
module.exports.geocodeAddress = geocodeAddress;
```

the other file is the one I use to execute the application.

```
const yargs = require('yargs');
const geocode = require('./geocode/geocode');
const argv = yargs
  .options({
    a:{
      demand: true,
      alias: 'Address',
      describe: 'Address to fetch weather for',
      string: true
    }
  })
  .help()
  .argv;

  geocode.geocodeAddress(argv.address)
```

when i run the second one in terminal, it says the zip code isn't long enough. I take that out, it spits out the next error, i take that out and the next one. No matter what I do it won't work. this code was working minutes before i put it in a function. I'm only a beginner and new to stackoverflow and I've been continuously trying to fix this problem, but I can't find a fix, so here I am. LMK if there is a problem with my formatting, I'm new to the forum, and most importantly, if you see any problems in the code, LMK!! Thanks in advance

Comment: is it possible that the aliases are case sensitive and you either need your alias to be `address` or you need to pass `argv.a` or `argv.Address` to geocode?

Comment: nope, i have confirmed they are not case sensitive and that's not your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like your code is fine, it's what you're expecting the data to be that is incorrect.

A simple `console.log` will show you that most of the returned locations contain no zipcode.

For instance, replace all your `else if`s with an `else` block that only contains `console.dir(body.results[0].locations[0])`. I tried out a couple; here's what the string `Houston` returns:

```
{
  street: '',
  adminArea6: '',
  adminArea6Type: 'Neighborhood',
  adminArea5: 'Houston',
  adminArea5Type: 'City',
  adminArea4: 'Harris County',
  adminArea4Type: 'County',
  adminArea3: 'TX',
  adminArea3Type: 'State',
  adminArea1: 'US',
  adminArea1Type: 'Country',
  postalCode: '',
  geocodeQualityCode: 'A5XAX',
  geocodeQuality: 'CITY',
  dragPoint: false,
  sideOfStreet: 'N',
  linkId: '282040105',
  unknownInput: '',
  type: 's',
  latLng: { lat: 29.760803, lng: -95.369506 },
  displayLatLng: { lat: 29.760803, lng: -95.369506 },
  mapUrl: <redacted>
 }
```

Note that the `postalCode` is the empty string which will fail all of your code's expectations.

Also, it's usually a bad idea to share your API key! Make sure you either change yours or setup permissions restricting what domains the requests can come from.

---

Now if you're only interested in locations *with* postal codes, filter all the others out:

```
let locations = body.results[0].locations;
let locationsOfInterest = locations.filter(location => (location.postalCode !== ''));
```

It's also worthwhile to note that your code probably does work for specific strings. For instance passing in `Boston Public Library` returns an address with a valid zipcode.

Comment: One more thing to note is that your code expects `latLng` to be an array of 2 elements, but is actually an object with `lat` and `lng` properties.

Comment: for me, it doesn't matter what I put in. I could put in Boston Public Library and I still get the same error.